# Dragonfly not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, dragonfly-gem

I am using Dragonfly with Nginx, unicorn and mini_magick. I am using mem_cache_store in production.

Image upload and display works fine in development environment. But on production it fails with internal server error 500. I cannot see any logs on my production log, but it fails on production.

I get error for URLs of following type.
http://cdn.mydomain.com/media/BAhbB1sHOgZmSSIoMTAvcHJvZHVjdHMvMjUvR3JvdW5kJTIwbnV0XzQwOS5qcGcGOgZFVFsIOgZwOgp0aHVtYkkiCjUweDUwBjsGVA.jpg

Error code is 500

I ve been searching all the documentation which comes along with the gem. I can see the following middleware on top of the middleware stack in production as well:

```
use Rack::Cache
use Dragonfly::CookieMonster
use Dragonfly::Middleware
```

I could not get much help from forums - though there is a similar bug posted 2 years ago and is supposed to be fixed. And fixes there also did not help.

Please help to fix this. Any direction as to how I can debug this would also help.

Comment: Can you run it "in production" locally, make logging useful (e.g. turn on `consider_all_requests_local`) and see if there's anything useful in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue like this and turned out that the problem was that I didnt have imagemagick installed in production. This post helped me [Dragonfly - Uploaded images not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476498/dragonfly-uploaded-images-not-displayed)

Btw I wasnt seeing any logs too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
Config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Sendfile, config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header
```

so that sendfile is before rack:cache and it should work.